# Which is faster/preferred: memset or for loop to zero out an array of doubles?

Tags: c++, c, performance, optimization

```
double d[10];
int length = 10;

memset(d, length * sizeof(double), 0);

//or

for (int i = length; i--;)
  d[i] = 0.0;
```

Comment: If you want to know what's **faster** you get the best answer by measuring it in your specific target environment(s).

Comment: Anyway, if you do it for initialization, `new` is always a good idea: `new double[N]()`

Comment: With current gcc/clang (early 2016): The loop compiles the same as `std::fill` [with gcc for x86](http://goo.gl/zNU7hQ): to a normal loop with 8B stores.  memset and an array initializer both compile to `rep stosq`.  clang likes to use AVX stores, rather than rep stosq, though.  Fun fact: gcc will optimize `malloc; memset ( ..., 0, ...)` to `calloc`, but clang doesn't.  clang compiles `std::fill` into a call to `memset`, though.

Comment: My `g++` appears to optimise `std::fill_n()` into `memset()`; I have a function that zeroes out a memory buffer, and without optimisations said function represents 50% of the `callgrind` time, but with optimisations it's nowhere to be seen... but there magically appear about 3% of calls (beyond other random stuff in supporting libs) to `__memset_sse2_unaligned`.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Note that for memset you have to pass the number of bytes, not the number of elements because this is an old C function:

```
memset(d, 0, sizeof(double)*length);
```

memset *can* be faster since it is written in assembler, whereas `std::fill` is a template function which simply does a loop internally.

But for type safety and more readable code **I would recommend** `std::fill()` - it is the c++ way of doing things, and consider `memset` if a performance optimization is needed at this place in the code.

Comment: Your sizeof use is wrong. It should be "sizeof (double)" or just "sizeof *d", but you can't mix the two. You need the parenthesis to get the size of a named type.

Comment: Sorry, there are plenty of implementations that specialize std::fill and std::copy for POD. And because these specializations can assume aligned pointers, they'll likely be faster than std::memset(). Memset has to deal with all edge cases.

Comment: +1 for std:fill(), this is the C++ way, unless a real need in performance is needed.

Comment: @StephaneRolland at least in GCC with `-O2` `std∷fill` **is** faster. You can check it for yourself by asking the compiler generate an assembly with `-S` option — you'd see that `memset` turn's out to be a call to a library function, whilst `std∷fill` becomes just a few assembly instructions without a `call` at all.

Comment: @Hi-Angel: As I commented on the OP, [depending on compile options](http://goo.gl/zNU7hQ), constant-size `memset` is inlined to `rep stosq`, which will perform very well (Probably better than the loop you get from `std::fill`, except for very small arrays because it has a little bit of startup overhead).

Comment: Are there additional optimizations that we can make if we know things about the buffer size, memory alignment, or page size ahead of time? I know the compiler will optimize `std::fill(x, x+1)`, for example. But if I have a large buffer that has some known alignment, there must be some performance improvements available over `memset`, right?

Comment: @MSalters: What is POD?

Comment: @AtulVaibhav: "Plain Old Data". Roughly means "a struct like you'd have in C". The exact meaning depends a bit on the C++ standard version (this question predates C++11), but it definitely means that the type has no user-defined constructor.

Answer (score 47):

If you really care you should try and measure. However the most portable way is using std::fill():

```
std::fill( array, array + numberOfElements, 0.0 );
```

Comment: `fill_n` then sounds more appropriate.

Comment: IMO the perfect answer. _If_ `std::memset()` is possible, I would expect the std lib implementation to call this, if not, it does the right thing, too.

Comment: @hacker: maybe, although I always assumed that fill_n is intended for use with iterators for which no end iterator exists, rather than in all cases where the length is known. But in this case it certainly does avoid repetition of "array".

Comment: Did you guys see this is A C question and NOT C++. AFAIK, C doesn't have fill function, much less std namespace

Comment: I swear it was tagged `c++` when it was first published! (not that I would prefer `c++` way here).

Comment: @hacker: Enigma retagged it as a C question about 1 minute before complaining about this answer.  Which is fine, though his comment strikes me as unjustly aggressive, when you take this into account.

Comment: Brian, agree on both accounts (retagging being fine, but not when coupled with unjust offense).

Comment: So I guess the answer to the question "did you guys see this is a C question", is "no, obviously not, because it was a C++ question". Am tempted to change the question to setting a Java array of doubles to 12.4, then complain that all the answers are irrelevant ;-)

Comment: @onebyone - don't forget to have at least 3 errors inthe Java code you post.

Comment: LOL @ onebyone, Michael Burr :)

Comment: @sbi: I would expect the std::lib to call `__memset_aligned_8` or so, not `std::memset()`. No point in doing a runtime alignment check on a `char*` if you know that it's just a casted `double*`

Comment: `std::fill_n(array, numberOfElements, 0)` is nicer and (given infinite time and code rot) less error-prone.

Answer (score 10):

Try this, if only to be cool xD

```
{
    double *to = d;
    int n=(length+7)/8;
    switch(length%8){
        case 0: do{ *to++ = 0.0;
        case 7:     *to++ = 0.0;
        case 6:     *to++ = 0.0;
        case 5:     *to++ = 0.0;
        case 4:     *to++ = 0.0;
        case 3:     *to++ = 0.0;
        case 2:     *to++ = 0.0;
        case 1:     *to++ = 0.0;
        }while(--n>0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you do that? Put cases inside a "do"?

Comment: @fbrereton: I'm snowed. I never realized the "case" could go down inside a subordinate block underneath the "switch".

Comment: yes, it's duff's device, I think other answer mentioned it... about the cases, they're just jump target labels FSMS knows what kind of unstructured tricks could be done with them! :-)

Comment: This probably made you cool when Tom Duff came out with it. Nowadays it probably makes the other programmers hate you. And (both) rightly so.

Comment: @sbi your inability to detect irony is fascinating

Comment: nobody should use this old piece of code. It confues most readers.

Comment: @frast it is good to filter out good programmers from bad ones xD

Comment: ... at the same time, the general idea can be accomplished without abusing the language so much. (Listen to me - I'm starting to sound judgemental!)

Comment: memset is probably faster. Some compilers implement it in assembly and do 128bit moves with cache prefetching. Can't really beat that.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming the loop length is an integral constant expression, the most probable outcome it that a good optimizer will recognize both the for-loop and the memset(0). The result would be that the assembly generated is essentially equal. Perhaps the choice of registers could differ, or the setup. But the marginal costs per double should really be the same.

Comment: I tested this with visual c++ and found that "std::fill_n(d, 1000000, 0.0f)" indeed compiles to 

    xor edx, edx
    mov r8d, 8000000    ; 007a1200H
    mov rcx, rax
    call memset

So for efficiency there really is no difference at all

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the several bugs and omissions in your code, using memset is not portable. You can't assume that a double with all zero bits is equal to 0.0. First make your code correct, then worry about optimizing.

Comment: You can make that assumption if you are using IEEE-754, and there are very few reasons to justify trying to make your floating-point code tolerant of implementations that wildly differ from the IEEE standard. In fact, the only reason I can imagine tolerating less than full compliance is if you are writing gpgpu code targeting a platform that doesn't implement all the rounding modes and NaN handling according to spec.

Comment: @unknown: Well, it's usually IEEE-754, but not always. So make sure by including `BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(numeric_limits<double>::is_iec559);` somewhere in your code. Then things will fail fast if the assumption is wrong.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Yeah, way late here, but Boost here is utterly nonsensical. Adding a dependency to Boost is bad enough, but limiting yourself to only MSVC, GCC, CLang, and Intel C++ (and ignoring C entirely...)  is going to help portability how?  Because those are the only compilers Boost supports.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: How you achieve fail-fast is not really important -- the point is to check your assumptions at compile time if at all possible. Modern C++ hass `static_assert`, which avoids the Boost dependency, and I just found out that C11 has `_Static_assert()`.

Answer (score 4):

```
memset(d,0,10*sizeof(*d));
```

is likely to be faster. Like they say you can also

```
std::fill_n(d,10,0.);
```

but it is most likely a prettier way to do the loop.

Comment: +1 for using count * sizeof, but you should drop the parenthesis too. :)

Comment: Note that, AFAIK, the standard doesn't guarantee that 0.0 is implemented as all bits set to 0. (In fact, all bits set to 0 might be an invalid floating point value that's trapped by the hardware.) So filling double with zeroed bytes is not portable and `std::memset()` shouldn't be used.

Comment: unwind, I like their roundness.

Comment: sbi, but we both now that it would work for our purpose ;-) Actually, the thing is — I doubt this is worth optimizing, but *if* for whatever reason we started to do so, then let's optimize it.

Comment: I prefer the `fill_n` way, since that one stays in the same context as the `double` variable.

Comment: xtofl, if we're talking loop vs `fill_n`, I'd certainly vote for `fill_n`. But *if* (**if!**) for whatever reason we want to speed up zeroing of half-a-gigabyte of doubles in the loop, I'd certainly care way less about the context.

Comment: @hacker: that seems to be the answer the OP was after.

Comment: Although I'm sure that "memset(d, length, 0);" is still much faster by far ;)

Comment: stefaanv, pardon my ignorance, but who is OP?;-)

Comment: @hacker - OP == "Original Poster"

Comment: @unwind - what's the problem with the parens?

Comment: @stefaanv: "Chen's Theorem of Ultimate Optimization": You can do nothing really fast.  From http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2008/10/14/8998849.aspx#8999794

Comment: Thanks, stefaanv. And with parens — I think unwind prefers it without — `sizeof *d`. A matter of taste.

Comment: @hacker: For a decade I have been writing code that had to run on dozens platforms and platform versions, compiled by almost half a dozen compilers or compiler versions being combined with several different std lib implementations. I have seen someone rake through >1.8MLoC for all C-style casts (because on one platform some of them caused a problem leading to crashes) and many other hellish tasks for porting code. One of the hardest lessons was that, whenever someone says "this piece of code will never have to be ported", never ever believe them. Such hard-learned habit sticks like tar.

Comment: @hacker: Note that I'd expect any decent implementation of `std::fill_n` to call `std::memset` if that is possible. But even if it doesn't, if you are zeroing 500MB once, I doubt that the speed difference really matters. And if you're doing this in a tight loop, there's still the code that has to repeatedly _fill_ 500MB with data it has to produce from somewhere -- and that, too, probably makes the zeroing irrelevant.

Comment: sbi, if the saving were irrelevant we wouldn't be here, if we talk about performance, then it is relevant in the scope of our talk. Other than that, what you're saying is valid, but you believe is strict rules and I don't mind breaking them. Having sticky habits should be balanced by being aware of it ;-)

Comment: I also don't quite get it why you first talking about portability across all kinds of platforms and then after barely taking a breath talk about assuming the decent implementation of `std::fill_n` ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Memset will always be faster, if debug mode or a low level of optimization is used. At higher levels of optimization, it will still be equivalent to std::fill or std::fill_n.
For example, for the following code under Google Benchmark:
(Test setup: xubuntu 18, GCC 7.3, Clang 6.0)

```
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>
#include <benchmark/benchmark.h>

double total = 0;


static void memory_memset(benchmark::State& state)
{
    int ints[50000];

    for (auto _ : state)
    {
        std::memset(ints, 0, sizeof(int) * 50000);
    }

    for (int counter = 0; counter != 50000; ++counter)
    {
        total += ints[counter];
    }
}


static void memory_filln(benchmark::State& state)
{
    int ints[50000];

    for (auto _ : state)
    {
        std::fill_n(ints, 50000, 0);
    }

    for (int counter = 0; counter != 50000; ++counter)
    {
        total += ints[counter];
    }
}


static void memory_fill(benchmark::State& state)
{
    int ints[50000];

    for (auto _ : state)
    {
        std::fill(std::begin(ints), std::end(ints), 0);
    }

    for (int counter = 0; counter != 50000; ++counter)
    {
        total += ints[counter];
    }
}


// Register the function as a benchmark
BENCHMARK(memory_filln);
BENCHMARK(memory_fill);
BENCHMARK(memory_memset);



int main (int argc, char ** argv)
{
    benchmark::Initialize (&argc, argv);
    benchmark::RunSpecifiedBenchmarks ();
    printf("Total = %f\n", total);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Gives the following results in release mode for GCC (-O2;-march=native):

```
-----------------------------------------------------
Benchmark              Time           CPU Iterations
-----------------------------------------------------
memory_filln       16488 ns      16477 ns      42460
memory_fill        16493 ns      16493 ns      42440
memory_memset       8414 ns       8408 ns      83022
```

## And the following results in debug mode (-O0):

```
-----------------------------------------------------
Benchmark              Time           CPU Iterations
-----------------------------------------------------
memory_filln       87209 ns      87139 ns       8029
memory_fill        94593 ns      94533 ns       7411
memory_memset       8441 ns       8434 ns      82833
```

While at -O3 or with clang at -O2, the following is obtained:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
Benchmark              Time           CPU Iterations
-----------------------------------------------------
memory_filln        8437 ns       8437 ns      82799
memory_fill         8437 ns       8437 ns      82756
memory_memset       8436 ns       8436 ns      82754
```

TLDR: use memset unless told you absolutely have to use std::fill or a for-loop, at least for POD types which are not non-IEEE-754 floating-points. There are no strong reasons not to.

*(note: the for loops counting the array contents are necessary for clang not to optimize away the google benchmark loops entirely (it will detect they're not used otherwise))*

Comment: For avoiding optimization of your code of interest, you can use those functions: https://gist.github.com/AlexisTM/2754f6b373bf40b544408a631abeb5ba

This is from a talk from Chandler Carruth on optimization: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nXaxk27zwlk&t=2446s

Answer (score 3):

```
calloc(length, sizeof(double))
```

According to IEEE-754, the bit representation of a positive zero is all zero bits, and there's nothing wrong with requiring IEEE-754 compliance. (If you need to zero out the array to reuse it, then pick one of the above solutions).

Comment: To make sure your assumption is correct, include `BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(numeric_limits<double>::is_iec559);` somewhere in your code.

Answer (score 3):

According to this Wikipedia article on [IEEE 754-1975 64-bit floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985#Double-precision_64_bit) a bit pattern of all 0s will indeed properly initialize a double to 0.0.  Unfortunately your memset code doesn't do that.

Here is the code you ought to be using:

```
memset(d, 0, length * sizeof(double));
```

As part of a more complete package...

```
{
    double *d;
    int length = 10;
    d = malloc(sizeof(d[0]) * length);
    memset(d, 0, length * sizeof(d[0]));
}
```

Of course, that's dropping the error checking you should be doing on the return value of malloc. `sizeof(d[0])` is slightly better than `sizeof(double)` because it's robust against changes in the type of d.

Also, if you use `calloc(length, sizeof(d[0]))` it will clear the memory for you and the subsequent memset will no longer be necessary.  I didn't use it in the example because then it seems like your question wouldn't be answered.

Comment: Doesn't the 0 need to be the 2nd argument to memset? Doesn't calloc clear what it allocates to zero?

Comment: Oops.  I should've been more careful with memset.  I'll fix that.  You're also right about calloc...  That's an interesting observation.  I'll change the code to use malloc, then mention calloc as an option.

Comment: However, the more important point is that C/C++ *do not* mandate IEEE 754 floating point! Although it is the most common representation, it is perfectly OK for a conforming compiler to use a different representation where all-bits-off in fact represents -42.69, so this code is not portable.

Comment: So don't drop the error checking. How hard is it to add "if (d) " in front of the memset. It's just 7 chars. It took you far more than 7 chars to note the lack of error checking. (And don't mention dangling elses, the block ends after the memset.)

Comment: Adding error checking increases the complexity of the example.  Clarity is more important than having the code be exactly correct when you're trying to show something.

Answer (score 2):

The example will not work because you have to allocate memory for your array. You can do this on the stack or on the heap.

This is an example to do it on the stack:

```
double d[50] = {0.0};
```

No memset is needed after that.

Comment: Spelling it out: if you supply an initialiser for an aggregate (struct or array), C and C++ will zero-initialise any remaining members.

Answer (score 1):

memset(d, 10, 0) is wrong as it only nulls 10 bytes.
prefer std::fill as the intent is clearest.

Comment: No, it doesn't null any bytes. It tens 0 bytes.

Comment: another reason to use std::fill

Comment: I do not hold anything against `std::fill`, but how is it *another reason*?

Comment: With memset, I always forget the order of the parameters, which I took over from the question.

Comment: I'd go as far as guessing that you forget the order of the parameters because you don't use it often enough ;-) And now go ahead and tell me you're not using it because you keep forgetting the order of parameters ;-)

Comment: I'm now considering, on principle, never again using any function that takes two integer parameters. Possible exception if the order doesn't matter, so std::min is OK ;-)

Comment: I'm not using it anymore because it is too lowlevel to do any real initialization and it is unsafe to initialize classes with it.
The only use for it is to initialize a real byte-buffer and you can do that too with std::fill

Comment: @stefaanv: since 99% of the time I call memset() to zero a buffer, I have a nice little inline:  inline void zeromem( void* p, size_t siz) { memset( p, 0, siz); } /* or something like that */.  Now I never need to worry about the order of the value and size.

Comment: stefaanv, of course it would be weird to try it on classes. But dismissing the function because it's not applicable in every single case goes a bit too far :)

Comment: PEBKAC isn't the fault of a C interface that's been around forever: `mam memset`

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to compare a properly optimized for loop if you really care about performance.

Some variant of Duff's device if the array is sufficiently long, and prefix --i not suffix i-- (although most compilers will probably correct that automatically.).

Although I'd question if this is the most valuable thing to be optimising. Is this genuinely a bottleneck for the system?

Comment: I think for primitive types it doesn't matter whether it's prefix or suffix (as long as result isn't used), but it's nice to develop an habit of using prefix whenever you don't care about the result — next loop may employ some complicated iterator instead.

Comment: Unrolled loops tend to suffer if they are bigger than the CPU's code cache line size.

Answer (score 0):

In general the memset is going to be much faster, make sure you get your length right, obviously your example has not (m)allocated or defined the array of doubles.  Now if it truly is going to end up with only a handful of doubles then the loop may turn out to be faster.  But as get to the point where the fill loop shadows the handful of setup instructions memset will typically use larger and sometimes aligned chunks to maximize speed.

As usual, test and measure. (although in this case you end up in the cache and the measurement may turn out to be bogus).

Answer (score 0):

One way of answering this question is to quickly run the code through Compiler Explorer: If you check this [link](https://godbolt.org/z/TGG11P), you'll see assembly for the following code:

```cpp
void do_memset(std::array<char, 1024>& a) {
    memset(&a, 'q', a.size());
}

void do_fill(std::array<char, 1024>& a) {
    std::fill(a.begin(), a.end(), 'q');
}

void do_loop(std::array<char, 1024>& a) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i) {
        a[i] = 'q';
    }
}
```

The answer (at least for `clang`) is that with optimization levels `-O0` and `-O1`, the assembly is different and `std::fill` will be slower because the use of the iterators is not optimized out. For `-O2` and higher, `do_memset` and `do_fill` produce *the same assembly*. The loop ends up calling `memset` *on every item* in the array even with `-O3`.

Assuming release builds tend to run `-O2` or higher, there are no performance considerations and I'd recommend using `std::fill` when it's available, and `memset` for C.

Answer (score -1):

If you're required to not use STL...

```
double aValues [10];
ZeroMemory (aValues, sizeof(aValues));
```

ZeroMemory at least makes the intent clear.

Comment: Why wouldst thy not use the stl when using C++?

Comment: @xtofl: It's probably not the case here but for example when using an older Symbian version, there is no STL available.

Comment: @onebyone - but ZeroMemory() has to be among the easiest functions to write out there.

Comment: @Michael: Yes, but is this a fast implementation then?

Comment: It's a macro that exapnds to a memset call. I just prefer it because it makes the intent clear, especially to a reader who isn't C-fluent.

Answer (score -1):

As an alternative to all stuff proposed, I can suggest you NOT to set array to all zeros at startup.  Instead, set up value to zero only when you first access the value in a particular cell.  This will stave your question off and may be faster.

Comment: How would it be faster? If the array truly needs to be zeroed out, then doing it on the fly would require a separate data structure to keep track of which entries are dirty, and lookups in that data structure would almost certainly take longer than just writing the zeros.

Comment: If you actually access first 100 cells out of 1 000 000 element array, setting it all to zeros is slower.  Especially if instead of that "structure" you just keep track of the lowest uninitialized index.

Comment: How is maintaining a separate structure faster in terms of maintenance?

Comment: How maintaining one integer number makes you call it a "structure"?

Answer (score -2):

I think you mean

```
memset(d, 0, length * sizeof(d[0]))
```

and

```
for (int i = length; --i >= 0; ) d[i] = 0;
```

Personally, I do either one, but I suppose `std::fill()` is probably better.

Comment: is fill better because it is faster? I need faster, not more readable :))))

Comment: I find the latter very cruel and unreadable. Initializing with length and not length-1 and doing the decrement inside the condition.

Comment: @enigma: Which is faster? I would have to time it, which you can do also. (Just wrap it in a 10^9 loop and look at your watch - seconds = nanoseconds.)

Comment: @codymanix: Cruel? Unreadable? (Sounds like ignorant professor-speak.) It's been done that way for ages, and that's how the processors used to do it also - very clean code.

Comment: @Mike: One thing to be aware of when you loop downwards like in your 2nd snippet is that the loop will run forever if `i` has unsigned type rather than signed as it does here.

Comment: @j: Absolutely right. Only intelligent coders need apply here.