# Memset on vector C++

Tags: c++, vector

Is there any equivalent function of `memset` for vectors in C++ ?

(Not `clear()` or `erase()` method, I want to retain the size of vector, I just want to initialize all the values.)

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Use [`std::fill()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill):

```
std::fill(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), 0);
```

Comment: If you're worried about efficiency, most STL implementations will have specialized std::fill implementations that do memsets where possible.

Comment: @razeh Currently, `-O3` is required for gcc to optimize fill to be as fast as memset. Clang only needs `-O2`. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/51274937/5267751)

Answer (score 30):

If your vector contains [POD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_data_structures) types, it is safe to use memset on it - the storage of a vector is guaranteed to be contiguous.

```
memset(&vec[0], 0, sizeof(vec[0]) * vec.size());
```

**Edit:** Sorry to throw an undefined term at you - POD stands for [Plain Old Data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_data_structures), i.e. the types that were available in C and the structures built from them.

**Edit again:** As pointed out in the comments, even though `bool` is a simple data type, `vector<bool>` is an interesting exception and will fail miserably if you try to use memset on it. [Adam Rosenfield's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665018/memset-on-vector-c/1665034#1665034) still works perfectly in that case.

Comment: Technically, a vector's storage isn't 100% guaranteed to be contiguous by the C++03 standard, but all implementations implement it that way, so memset is indeed safe with POD types.  C++0x fixes the problem and requires all vector implementations to use contiguous storage.

Comment: Really? I thought it was common knowledge that a `vector`'s memory had to be contiguous. Is that just a rumor?

Comment: @GMan: Yep.  Take a look at section 23.2.4 of the C++03 draft standard at ftp://ftp.research.att.com/dist/c++std/WP/CD2/body.pdf .  Nowhere does it mention contiguous storage.

Comment: @GMan: IIRC, the std::vector<bool> specialization is a counterexample, and probably the most well-known one.

Comment: In my copy of the ISO03 standard, on page 489 [23.2.4], it says: "The elements of a
`vector` are stored contiguously, meaning that if v is a `vector<T, Allocator>` where T is some type
other than `bool`, then it obeys the identity `&v[n] == &v[0] + n` for all `0 <= n < v.size()`." I think that means contiguous, right?

Comment: I was under the impression that contiguous storage was guaranteed by the current standards - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247738/is-it-safe-to-assume-that-stl-vector-storage-is-always-contiguous

Comment: Well, yeah, `std::vector<bool>` has always been a pain in the-- a super duper helpful specialization.

Comment: But to fair, it really doesn't say it in the draft, so if the draft is your personal standard that could be misleading. Comment +1 just for noticing. :)

Comment: @Adam Rosenfield: you may be thinking of strings being contiguous or not.  As for vectors, "contiguity is in fact part of the vector abstraction. It’s so important, in fact, that when it was discovered that the C++98 standard didn’t completely guarantee contiguity, the C++03 standard was amended to explicitly add the guarantee" from http://herbsutter.wordpress.com/2008/04/07/cringe-not-vectors-are-guaranteed-to-be-contiguous/

Comment: And as far as `vector<bool>` being an exception, `vector<bool>` has many other problems and anomalies: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/1999/n1185.pdf and various other papers on problems with `vector<bool>`

Comment: You're right, I'm mistaken.  I think it was the C++98 standard that didn't guarantee contiguous storage and the C++03 standard fixed that.  But, as I only have the draft standard and not the real standard, I can't be certain.

Comment: @Adam: C++98 did not require that vector is contiguous explicitly. Interestingly enough the TC was accepted before the standard was published - re: http://www.comeaucomputing.com/iso/lwg-defects.html#69

Answer (score 5):

You can use `assign` method in vector:

Assigns new contents to the vector, replacing its current contents, and modifying its size accordingly(if you don't change vector size just pass vec.size() ).

For example:

```
vector<int> vec(10, 0);
for(auto item:vec)cout<<item<<" ";
cout<<endl;
// 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 

// memset all the value in vec to 1,  vec.size() so don't change vec size
vec.assign(vec.size(), 1); // set every value -> 1

for(auto item:vec)cout<<item<<" ";
cout<<endl;
// 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Cited:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/assign/

Answer (score 2):

Another way, I think I saw it first in Meyers book:

```
// Swaps with a temporary.
vec.swap( std::vector<int>(vec.size(), 0) );
```

Its only drawback is that it makes a copy.

Answer (score 1):

m= Number of Rows
&& n== Number of Columns

```
vector<vector<int>> a(m,vector<int>(n,0));
```