# How to check whether an unsigned char vector contains all null characters

Tags: c++, vector, null, c++98

I need to check whether my vector contains all null characters and perform some operation based on that result. I found couple of questions in Stack overflow but they are not exactly matching my requirement.

One solution that I can think of to decide a vector with all null characters is:

```
if(Buffer[0] == '\0') {
 std::cout<<"vector contains all NULL characters";
}
```

If there is any better way for this, please share your idea.

Complete code is:

File1.cpp:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> Buffer(BufferSize, 0);
```

File2.cpp:

```
try
{
    // do some operation, if no exception then fill the buffer
    // if exception then go to catch block
}
catch(...)
{
    memset(Buffer, '\0', BufferSize); 
}
```

After this, in File1.cpp I just get Buffer, filled with valid data or '\0'.

This is in C++ 98

Comment: Your first snippet of code only checks the first character. Why not `clear()` the vector, or use a `std::optional<std::vector<unsigned char>>`?

Comment: Don't use `memset` for a container, use [`std::fill`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1665034/4123703).

Comment: @Botje I should not edit that buffer due some dependencies from other files

Comment: @LouisGo I have used `memset()` because in File2.cpp buffer is taken as `unsigned char * `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`std::all_of()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) algorithm to check if all of the elements meets a condition.
I hope you see `std::any_of()` and `std::none_of()` also.

```
int BufferSize = 30;
vector<unsigned char> Buffer(BufferSize, 0);
bool is_clear = std::all_of(Buffer.cbegin(), Buffer.cend(), [](unsigned char c) {return c == 0; });
```

For the cases where `C++11` is not available you can implement any_of like this:

```
bool is_clear=true;
for(size_t i=0; i<Buffer.size(); ++i)
{
  if(Buffer[i]!=0)
  {
    is_clear=false;
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: @explorer2020, Then using loop and checking each of element is possible. I edited my answer for it, but I'm not sure it works in C++98 because I'm not used to the standard.

Comment: In my case if(Buffer[0] == '\0') {} is better than the loop as I have huge data in the vector. But your answer is helpful, so accepted as the answer :) Thank you.

Comment: @explorer2020, Good to hear that it was helpful for you. Maybe you can find better option in C++98, as I'm not used to the standard.