# is memset(ary,0,length) a portable way of inputting zero in double array

Tags: c, floating-point, double, ieee-754, memset

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is faster/prefered memset or for loop to zero out an array of doubles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373369/what-is-faster-prefered-memset-or-for-loop-to-zero-out-an-array-of-doubles)

The following code uses memset to set all the bits to zero

```
int length = 5;
double *array = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double)*length);
memset(array,0,sizeof(double)*length);
for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
  if(array[i]!=0.0)
    fprintf(stderr,"not zero in: %d",i);
```

Can I assume that this will work on all platforms?

Does the double datatype always correspond to the ieee-754 standard?

thanks for your replies,
and thanks for the ::fill template command. But my question was more in the sense of the double datatype.

Maybe I should have written my question for pure c.
But thanks anyway.

EDIT: changed code and tag to c

Comment: Dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373369/what-is-faster-prefered-memset-or-for-loop-to-zero-out-an-array-of-doubles

Comment: AFAIK, technically, `0.0` doesn't need to be represented by a bit pattern with all bits zero. Follow [Viktor's advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948258/2948273#2948273) and if it works that way on a platform I'd expect an implementation of `std::fill()` to invoke `std::memset()` internally.

Comment: @Matthew What difference do you think that makes?

Comment: `new` is not part of C.  You need to use malloc or calloc or change the tag back to C++.

Comment: @JeremeyP yes of cause, sorry about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are in a C99 environment, you get no guarantee whatsoever. The representation of floating point numbers is defined in § 5.2.4.2.2, but that is only the logical, mathematical representation. That section does not even mention how floating point numbers are stored in terms of bytes. Instead, it says in a footnote:

> The floating-point model is intended to clarify the description of each floating-point characteristic and does not require the floating-point arithmetic of the implementation to be identical.

Further, § 6.2.6.1 says:

> The representations of all types are unspecified except as stated in this subclause.

And in the rest of that subclause, floating point types are not mentioned.

In summary, there is no guarantee that a `0.0` is represented as all-bits-zero.

Answer (score 3):

Use `::std::fill(array, array+length, 0.0);`

Comment: fill_n() is only useful if your container doesn't provide random access.

Answer (score 3):

It's not portable. Just use loop.
You don't need to cast malloc return value.