# Reinitialize array in while-loop

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

Let say I have the following array

```
 char ch[1000];
```

And I initialize this char

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
   ch[i] = 0;
}
```

And then I want to use this array in a while loop

```
 bool active = true;
 int i = 0;
 while(active) {


     ch[i] = ....... // fill the array with certain ashii 

     // code 
     strcpy(string, ch); // after this - I may go back to the top of the loop and startover   

     i++;
 }
```

The loop does not really look like this in reality - but this is only schematic. The issue is here (and my question) - IF I now want to use this char-array again in the loop - that is go to the top of the while loop and fill the char-variable with new characters, what is the best way to empty the array from old characters.

1) change the code so that I declare this buffer WITHIN the while-loop

It does not seem efficient to reinitialize it again with a for loop as I did outside the loop

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
   ch[i] = 0;
 }
```

This approach seem to demand a lot of cpu-instructions

Are there better ways to do this?

Comment: You do not "empty an array", you just reuse it. Also, there's really no sense in zeroing all elements if you are only interested in those you explicitly overwrite afterwards. It just costs time and code.

Comment: What is `i` in your while loop?

Comment: If you say `char ch[1000] = {};` you already get a zero-initialized array. No need for a loop.

Comment: @anders: AFAICT, it is about using an array of char for some purpose, and you (re-)initialise it, having the misconception that you can "empty an array" or must "(re-)reinitialise" it before (re-)use. I addressed that point, because the most efficient and elegant code is omitted code.

Comment: It isn't clear what you are using the `char[]` array for, but perhaps you should consider using `std::string`, `std::vector` or `std::array` instead?

Answer (score 3):

Notice that you can overwrite the entries of the array. Think if you really need to re-initialize. If not, overwriting will suffice.

Moreover, you could use the initializer list, `{}`, which will set the entries of the array to their default value, which for `int` is `zero`.

Overwriting example with an array that I first want to fill with zeros and then with ones.

```
int a[N] = {}; // I am initialised to the default value already!
int v = 0;
while(v < 2) {
  for(int i =0; i < N; ++i) {
    a[i] = v;
  }
  ++v;
}
```

You could use [`memset`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memset/) or [`std::fill`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/fill/) to re-initialize your array.

I do not suggest creating again the array, because internally the language should search for contigius memory cells and then allocate them. And every time the loop ends, it should de-allocate the array.

Re-initialization must be faster.

[EDIT]

[`std::fill` or `memset`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373369/which-is-faster-preferred-memset-or-for-loop-to-zero-out-an-array-of-doubles)

The trade-off is that `memset` can be faster, where `std::fill` is more safe.

Notice that the first one is a `C` function, where the second a `C++` one.

Comment: Local arrays are not initialized by default. Your `a[N]` contains stack garbage until you actually initialize it.

Comment: The initializer list will set the elements of `a[N]` to their default value.

Comment: `int a[N];` has no initializer list.

Comment: !!!! Probably deleted it when writing the comment. I will edit, thanks @T.C..

Comment: I would highly recommend `std::fill` over `memset` in C++

Comment: @tenfour, good point, I will edit so that the answer is improved. :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply reuse the array, and reinitialize its values using another for loop. That would probably be your best bet.