# C increment pointer vs for() loop performance

Tags: c, performance

I was always wondering, is it in all cases equivalent to write this way:

```
char* op = buf;
int l = buflen;
while( l > 0 )
{
    *op = bufval;
    op++;
    l--;
}
```

and this way:

```
int l;
for( l = 0; l < buflen; l++ )
{
    buf[ l ] = bufval;
}
```

from a wide range of modern compilers and computing platforms performance perspective? The latter code is of course more elegant, but that's not the point. I see that check "l greater than 0" is like a simple JNZ in assembler terms while "l lesser than bufval" requires comparison op. "buf[l]" may not require an additional instruction relative to "op++", but I do not know how this affects performance in practice. The first variant is preferrable in some cases like when "op" needs to be incremented by 3, that's far better than writing "l*3" I suppose.

Comment: Microoptimizations by the programmer rarely make much of a difference.  Compilers have gotten incredibly good at understanding the essence of what you mean, and picking the most efficient implementation given the processor at hand, no matter how you write it.  So I'd say, don't worry about it.

Comment: Sometimes your own microoptimizations can make it worse. For example swapping values in an Array with _XOR_ instead of using an temporary variable could prevent the compiler from optimizing it.

Comment: `memset(buf, bufval, buflen)` **might** be faster than both of these https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373369/which-is-faster-preferred-memset-or-for-loop-to-zero-out-an-array-of-doubles. However, note that you can use `memset` safely only because `buf` is a `char*`.

Comment: If you want to see which is better, consider looking at the assembler output under a reasonable optimization level on the platforms that matter to you.  Compare and contrast — and don't be surprised if they compare the same so there is no contrast.  In the `for` loop, there are two additions (one from subscripting); in the `while` loop, there's one addition and one subtraction.  There's not going to be a lot of measurable performance difference.  If you can't deduce from the assembler output, go and measure the results, but be careful — performance measurement is a tricky business.

Comment: use the corrent types first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the generated assembly for both the code snippets

```
f2:                          ;; pointer based approach
        test    edx, edx
        jle     .L5
        sub     edx, 1
        movsx   esi, sil
        movsx   rdx, edx
        add     rdx, 1
        jmp     memset
.L5:
        ret

f3:                          ;; loop based approach
        test    edx, edx
        jle     .L8
        sub     edx, 1
        movsx   esi, sil
        add     rdx, 1
        jmp     memset
.L8:
        ret
```

I understand that shorter assembly does not mean faster code, however the compiler does generate a few extra instructions for the pointer based version. The difference in number of instructions is even larger when I tried the same using clang. If anything, the pointer based version will be a little slower, not faster.

Note that both of these are calling `memset` and the code prior to that is merely checking and setting up the registers for that call to `memset`. You can go ahead and make the `memset` call yourself.

```
memset(buf, bufval, buflen)
```

This generates the following assembly

```
f1:                          ;; memset based approach
        movsx   rdx, edx
        jmp     memset
```

Coming back to the original question, which version is faster. It cannot be emphasised enough that modern compilers are smart. Micro-optimizations like these rarely, if ever, provide performance benefits. Writing idiomatic code, where it is easier for compiler to understand the intent, will always give you better performance.

Here is a link to godbolt if you want to play with the assembly output: https://godbolt.org/g/NxHS5F

Comment: Also note that if one has a particular streak of masochism, they can further dissect the instructions to determine which ones stall on the pipeline, and what the clocks are for each individual instruction. Having more (or fewer) instructions does not necessarily equate to slower (or faster) code. It isn't that simple. Even more reason to trust the professional compiler authors to generate optimized code, and only dive in to the deep end when you can *prove* there is a unexpected bottleneck *and* you can prove a way to circumvent it.

Comment: Change `int buflen` to `size_t buflen` and the prep code the compiler generates goes down on all three versions.

Comment: @BenVoigt: `l` should have a type of `size_t` as well, and the named changed to something else to avoid confusion with the number `1`.

Answer (score 2):

The difference youy see is only because your functions are written in a very compiler optimizer unfriendly and bad way.

Both should compile the same if they are better written:

```
void foo(char *buf, int bufval, size_t buflen)
{
    while(buflen--)
    {
        *buf++ = bufval;
    }
}


void foo1(char *buf, int bufval, size_t buflen)
{

    size_t l;
    for( l = 0; l < buflen; l++ )
    {
        buf[ l ] = bufval;
    }
}


foo:
        test    rdx, rdx
        je      .L11
        movsx   esi, sil
        jmp     memset
.L11:
        ret
foo1:
        test    rdx, rdx
        je      .L14
        movsx   esi, sil
        jmp     memset
.L14:
        ret
```

Quality of the optimization is 80% on programmers side. If you write programs like in your question, you will always get the poor machine code.

## ****EDIT****

Same with `-fno-builtin`

```
void foo(char *buf, int bufval, size_t buflen)
{
    while(buflen--)
    {
        *buf++ = bufval;
    }
}


void foo1(char *buf, int bufval, size_t buflen)
{

    size_t l;
    for( l = 0; l < buflen; l++ )
    {
        buf[ l ] = bufval;
    }
}

foo:
        lea     rax, [rdi+rdx]
        test    rdx, rdx
        je      .L9
.L11:
        add     rdi, 1
        mov     BYTE PTR [rdi-1], sil
        cmp     rdi, rax
        jne     .L11
.L9:
        ret
foo1:
        lea     rax, [rdi+rdx]
        test    rdx, rdx
        je      .L15
.L17:
        mov     BYTE PTR [rdi], sil
        add     rdi, 1
        cmp     rdi, rax
        jne     .L17
.L15:
        ret
```

Comment: To be fair to OP, the thing that made a difference (whether the type of the length variables is `int` or `size_t`) wasn't "bad" in the question, it just mismatched the `memset` call that the compiler wants to use.  The compiler actually saw right through the code cleanliness things, like needless temporary variables and those didn't affect the machine code.

Comment: same is with the  `-fno-builtin`.  See my amended answer