# Practical advantages of std::copy, std::equal, std::fill over memcpy, memset, memcmp

Tags: c++, memcpy, memset, memcmp

A few posts compare the performance between C++-style functions `std::copy, std::equal, std::fill` with C-style functions `std::memcpy, std::memcmp, std::memset`, for example :

- [memcpy vs std::copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707012/is-it-better-to-use-stdmemcpy-or-stdcopy-in-terms-to-performance?rq=1),
- [memset vs std::fill](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51274937/18316497),
- [memcmp vs std::equal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3616164/18316497)

But I haven't found what justifies the replacement by these new functions over the old one from a practical point of view. Of course, the list of functions is not exhaustive.

What are the practical advantages of these new versions ?

If performance is not a criterion for choosing, is it desirable (time permitting) to replace all occurrences of these C-style functions with the C++ versions ?

I tried to understand why some functions have been introduced in `c++` and if it is necessary to do the  replacement.

Comment: Bitwise copying/comparison is unsuitable for many class types, such as containers or anything that contains one as a member. *"no need to downvote only for tag-edit"* I didn't downvote.

Comment: Ahh it calls overloaded operators, sorry for my misunderstanding ! Nevertheless, honestly I don't understand why I harvest a bunch of downvote for it..

Comment: No worries. Downvotes are probably from people who think it's too easy to google the answer.

Comment: @kingsjester It's the opposite, the "new functions" are more "practical" but less performant.

Comment: @Fareanor Got any sources for "less performant"? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9980859/2752075) says almost the same performance.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat [Here is your source](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy)

Comment: @Fareanor What am I suppoesd to see here? I see *"meant to be the fastest library routine for memory-to-memory copy"*, but I also see *"Several C++ compilers transform suitable memory-copying loops to std::memcpy calls."*.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat The whole sentence is: _"std::memcpy is meant to be the fastest library routine for memory-to-memory copy. It is usually more efficient than std::strcpy, which must scan the data it copies or std::memmove, which must take precautions to handle overlapping inputs."_

Comment: try to `memset` all elements of a `std::list` or `std::map` or really anything that does not use contiguous memory and you will notice an important difference

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Anyway, profiling in our everyday-use machines is hard to get right (for example, measuring the CPU time without fixing the CPU clock is meaningless). Plus some compilers may replace `std::copy` calls with equivalent `std::memcpy` calls with optimization enabled, so without looking at the assembly code, the answer you linked does not say much, it claims more than the evidences allows it to claim.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai ok, and when the memory used is contiguous, the replacement is useless ?

Comment: @kingsjester not, its not useless. The compiler can do it.

Comment: The down votes come for *"Many posts..."*. You should've instead, provided citations and references to benchmarks or articles. If you can rephrase the first paragraph into a humble question - instead of a bold and false claim - I will try to cancel one of those downvotes. Nevertheless, those *Many posts* don't seem to be true.

Comment: @Red.Wave done as requested.

Comment: If you had carefully examined those threads, the claim for better performance of **mem** functions over STL algorithms is part of the questions, but the common divisor of the replies - including the accepted answers - is that the claim is false. Up until C++20, `memcpy` used to be the only reliable method for type-punning. Since C++20, that use case is fulfilled with `std::bit_cast` in a safe manor, without any caveats, pitfalls or mistakes that could happen with `memcpy`. Moreover, `std::bit_cast` can be used in `constexpr` contexts too. Please never use **mem** functions in modern C++ code.

Comment: If the element type is wider than `char`, `memset` can only fill it with values whose bytes have the same bit pattern (try to fill an `int` arrays with ones (`1`) using both `memset` and `std::fill` and see what happens). `memcmp` is useless with arrays of structures as it also compares padding.

Comment: I have some difficulty believing that the performance problems that can be found in an implementation come from these functions (C-style or C++-style). The only thing that can provoke a performance cost in these is allocation during repetitive call to the constructor. Therefore, it depends of the implementation of this constuctor. This debate appears disconnected from reality.

Comment: @Fareanor The new functions are more general. And by the as-if rule, in the situations where they have equivalent observable behaviour, the new functions can just inline as the old functions, so they can be equivalently performant

Comment: @Caleth You're right, it wasn't an advice to keep using the old at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I haven't found what justifies the replacement by these new functions over the old one from a practical point of view.

These functions are more general. `memcpy` and `memset` are only defined for contiguous ranges of types that are *TriviallyCopyable*, and `memcmp` is (generally) only meaningful for contiguous ranges of *TriviallyCopyable* types with no padding. N.b. a single object is vacuously a contiguous range of length one.

Performance is only comparable when they do the same things, and by the as-if rule, an implementation can choose to implement a call to `std::copy` in exactly the same way as it does `memcpy` when it can prove the ranges don't overlap, or `memmove` otherwise. Similarly `std::fill` with `memset` and `std::equal` with `memcmp`<sup>1</sup>.

1. slightly modified, because it doesn't care about less or greater, just equal

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. 

It also answers to this question : "If performance is not a criterion for choosing, is it desirable (time permitting) to replace all occurrences of these C-style functions with the C++ versions ?" -> Yes, for portability between contiguous and TriviallyCopyable types to non-contiguous or non-TriviallyCopyable types.

Answer (score 3):

As has been pointed out in the comments, `std::copy`, etc. work, where as `std::memcpy`, ect. only work in a very limited number of cases. In particular, `std::memcpy` doesn't work for anything with an non-trivial constructor, so for none of the standard containers. Even when used on a C style `struct`, or a C style array of `struct`s, it only does a shallow copy, so depending on the semantics of the object, it may not work even on a C style `struct` which contains a pointer.

With regards to performance, nothing is of course guaranteed. But the compiler will have access to the source of `std::copy` (because it is a template), and will typically be able to inline it -- for C style `struct`s, this would usually result in copying in larger chunks (machine words, rather than bytes). In the case of `std::memcpy`, there is typically a function call, which hides any information about the underlying context, and requires either a byte-wise copy (resulting a lot more times in the loop), or complicated logic for handling alignment and a possible odd number of bytes. The C standard does allow `memcpy` to be a macro, resolving to a special symbol which triggers some sort of compiler optimization, but I don't think this is legal in C++. And some earlier, pre-(C)standard C compilers did recognize `memcpy` as if it were a keyword, in order to generate inline code. But this is all in the very distant past (before the first C standard).

In today's C++ code, there is absolutely no reason to use `std::memcpy`, ever.

Comment: The part about `memcpy` is very misleading. The compilers can and do have special knowledge about functions without them being macros or keywords, and indeed all three big compilers can optimize away `memcpy`. GCC and Clang do it even at `-O0`, while MSVC needs `/O2`: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/vqE7jqG3T

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I don't see it in the generated code: `g++ -S -O3` or `cl /c /O2 /Fa`. (I don't have clang installed.) Maybe the optimization is only present in C. (I know that some C compilers had it in the 1980s.) I wouldn't expect it in a C++ compiler, since I wouldn't expect C++ code to use `memcpy`. But maybe it depends on the context -- I just wrote a simple function which did nothing but call `memcpy` on its arguments.

Comment: You mean you don't see `memcpy`? That would indicate that the compiler optimized it away, hence it has to have special knowledge about it to be able to do so.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I mean that I don't see the optimization. With optimization, both compilers end the function with a jump to `memcpy` (since the call is the last thing in my test function), after having fiddled a bit with the registers so that the arguments to `memcpy` are where they should be.

Comment: Here's GCC optimizing it away: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/v14Kjc8nc Here's MSVC: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/hMf9ozExs And I've posted Clang above. All of those are compiled as C++.

Comment: Interesting. So it does depend on context. (I believe I mentioned that it might.) My tests involved calling it on an arbitrary buffer, where it wasn't optimized away. So the compilers treat `std::copy` and `std::memcpy` more or less the same when the information that `std::copy` has is available at the call site.

Answer (score 2):

`memset` has two drastic limitations.

First the container. You can only `memset` more than a single element to a container that uses contiguous memory. It can work for `std::array` or `std::vector` but not for most other containers.

Next, the elements. You can only `memset` trivially copyable objects. Already something as "simple" as `std::string` is not trivially copyable.

`memset` can be used in some cases. The other functions you mention are more generally applicable and when they can be replaced by `memset` the compiler can do that.

Comment: The compiler could replace `std::copy` with `memset` in some cases. This would almost always be pessimisation, however, as generating the code directly inline would typically be several times faster, and likely smaller than the code needed to set up the function call.

Comment: @JamesKanze good to read from you after a long time. Don't repeat OP's typo please! `std::copy` normally correspondes to `std::memcpy`.